# unable to load map into my flutter app using mapmyindia_gl package

Tags: flutter, mapmyindia-api

MapmyIndiaAccountManager.setMapSDKKey("bearer *accessToken*");
MapmyIndiaAccountManager.setRestAPIKey("REST / Map SDK Key From mappls dashboard");
MapmyIndiaAccountManager.setAtlasClientId("*ClientId*");
MapmyIndiaAccountManager.setAtlasClientSecret("*ClientSecret*");

And Then use this

static const CameraPosition _kInitialPosition = CameraPosition(
target: LatLng(25.321684, 82.987289),
zoom: 14.0,
);

MapmyIndiaMap(
initialCameraPosition: _kInitialPosition,
)

[Attach Image of Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItIoG.png)

Comment: can you share the full code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.